# cURL get_data($url) with absolute URL

Tags: php, curl

I'm using this code to get data using cURL

```
$url='http://example.com/'; //URL to get content from..
print_r(get_data($url)); //Dumps the content

/* Gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
```

However, This code returns data with relative url. How can I get ride of this relative url & print with absolute url? May be with preg_replace.. But How ?

Comment: You mean you want to convert the links in returned data from relative to absolute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the HTML [`base`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4) tag. You should find it helpful if you want to let the browser do all the relative-to-absolute conversion:

```
$data = get_data($url);
// Note: ideally you should use DOM manipulation to inject the <base>
// tag inside the <head> section
$data = str_replace("<head>", "<head><base href=\"$url\">", $data);
echo $data;
```

Comment: Awesome! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: This returns a "Headers already sent" error in my site. What can I do about that?

Comment: +1 for good, simple solution that uses often-overlooked tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must to use a HTML parser like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/, and replace all links with the correct path.